# how to make loader for component view wise in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, components, loader

i have try to make loader for every component view when view load than hide loader. view data come from api

my component structure is like below in my `<app-main></app-main>`

```
<app-banner></app-banner>
<app-data></app-data>
<app-users></app-users>
```

no i have make loader for every component when load view from api data

loader for `banner, data, users` when data load loader show after get data loader hide

how can i make loader like this way

Comment: just use IsdataLoaded=false; variable in your component.ts file and set it to true in your http response; then use *ngIf="IsdataLoaded" in your tags (**app-banner, app-data, app-user**)

Answer (score 0):

you must make a `<app-loader></app-loader>` component

it should be sharable

just keep inside the `<main-app></main-app>`

and  ngOninit() of the individual components just make the `<app-loader></app-loader>` invisble on when response is available

Answer (score 0):

Try to use and @Input for your loader component :

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-loader",
    templateUrl: ["./app-loader.component.html"]
})
export default class LoaderComponent{
  @Input() isLoaded: boolean = false;
  ...
}
```

and add if to your template